# Accessing vector.front() in a thread causes runtime error

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I have a strange issue with vectors, I initialize a class member vector in the main thread and then call a thread which try to access the **front()** of that vector. But accessing the vector front causes a runtime error

Here is code for main thread (**dispatchQueue** is a private class member of class **Engine**)

```
dispatchQueue.push_back(TempObj);
boost::thread processThread(&Engine::initializeExecutorService, this);
processThread.start_thread();
processThread.join();
```

And the code for member function **initializeExecutorService** is as follows (**processingQueue** is a private class member)

```
while (nextIterationAvailable) {
    if (pendingProcess) {

        processingQueue.push_back(dispatchQueue.front());
        dispatchQueue.pop_back();
    }
}
```

The **initializeExecutorService** works fine if I call it with main thread

**UPDATE**

The Debugger reports

> Signal received: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) For program postmaster-cpp-ng-obj, pid 13,614
>   You may discard the signal or forward it and you may continue or pause the process

When I try to run with Netbeans it reports

> RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped;

Running with **gdb** shows

> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
>   Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
>   [New Thread 0x7ffff68e8700 (LWP 13821)]
>   [New Thread 0x7ffff60e7700 (LWP 13822)]
>   [New Thread 0x7ffff58e6700 (LWP 13823)]
>   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   [Switching to Thread 0x7ffff60e7700 (LWP 13822)]
>   0x00007ffff79cba1b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0

Comment: Please edit your post and add the exact error.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the `dispatchQueue` is being modified and read from simultaneously? Your code as-is should be working, but it is possible that in your actual situation, there you are missing necessary mutexes.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but your code gets the front of the queue, but pops the back?

Comment: @Mankarse multiple threads are accessing the dispatchQueue but not at the same time,

Comment: @Kami, well are you sure they aren't?

Comment: Let the debugger tell you where and what went wrong. Running `gdb [yourprogram]` and then pressing `r` should do it after compiling with `-g`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg program dies before reaching the pop_back

Comment: @lethal-guitar I am sure, as you can see there is a flag pendingProcess both the threads access the dispatchQueue on opposite values of that flag

Comment: And how is `pendingProcess` synchronized?

Comment: @Kami the only way to be sure is to check in the debugger - it can show you which thread is executing what at the time of the segfault.

Comment: Do the first `front` call crash? Or are there multiple iterations of the loop before the crash happens? And anyway it looks like a logical error that you should really look at. What if the vector have multiple entries, then you're probably removing the wrong entry.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the first call crashes, interestingly when I call the same code with main thread it works fine

Comment: All we can really tell you without an SSCE is that you probably have a data race somewhere (program works single-threaded, crashes multi-threaded) or a logic error in your belief that `nextIterationAvailable && pendingProcess` implies `!dispatchQueue.empty()`.

Comment: @Casey after I am finished working with dispatchQueue in one thread I change the flag so other thread can use it, and then follow the same procedure for the other thread as well

Comment: can you add the code pieces from the other threads (which access `pendingProcess` and `dispatchQueue`) ?  Without that its blind guessing which could be wrong and won't help much.

Comment: `bool`s are not process synchronization. If you set `pendingProcess` true before inserting an item into the queue, the other thread can run and try to access the queue before the first thread has inserted the item. 

Also, even if your queue will only ever have one item in it, make all access from the same end. If you use `dispatchQueue.back()` instead of `dispatchQueue.front()` no one will question why you're using the front item, but popping the back of the queue. It removes that confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::front` fails when the vector is empty.

This is a safe version:

```
// lock dispatchQueue
if(!dispatchQueue.empty()) {
    processingQueue.push_back(dispatchQueue.front());
    dispatchQueue.pop_back();
}
// unlock dispatchQueue
```

Additionally using the first element and removing the last looks dubious.

Comment: Actually this is not safe without locking the **dispatchQueue** before checking if it is empty or not. Besides I know the **dispatchQueue** is not empty and it will never be when this code will be called due to the flag **pendingProcess**

Comment: _Additionally using the first element and removing the last looks dubious._
At any time there is only one item in the vector so first and last item is the same

Comment: @Kami: 1) It was not thread-safe in the first place. 2) Then why do you need/use a queue?

Comment: 1) I don't need thread-safety as I am not going to make concurrent changes to the dispatchQueue

2) It's not a queue its a vector queue don't have push_back and pop_back functions they are simply push and pop

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Danvil's response, I would like to add a note. May be this could help, as once I have faced similar issue in a multithreaded application.

You should also check whether dispatchQueue state is valid or not. In our application another thread was deleting the vector and it was crashing below code snippet.

```
if(myvector.size)
```

We have used Windbg to diagnose the issue.